# Polymer issues with contenteditable, execCommand, and insertunorderedlist

Tags: javascript, polymer, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm writing a very basic WYSIWYG rich editor using Polymer 2.0 and `contenteditable`  attribute of a `div` but experiencing issues with `document.execCommand` and executing the command `insertunorderedlist`. If you select and highlight the text you want to insert an unordered list and click button then it either fails to work correctly using Chrome (latest version) or if using Safari (latest version High Sierra), just hangs. If you try this outside of Polymer (plain old html and javascript) it works fine. Any ideas how to get this working with Polymer 2.0? Here's my code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-module id="polymerbasic-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <button on-click="_insertunorderedlist" type="button">Insert Unordered List</button>

    <div id="textBox" contenteditable="true">
      Bullet One
      <br> Bullet Two
      <br> Bullet Three
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class PolymerbasicApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'polymerbasic-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'polymerbasic-app'
          }
        };
      }

      _insertunorderedlist() {
        document.execCommand("insertunorderedlist", false, null); this.$.textBox.focus();
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(PolymerbasicApp.is, PolymerbasicApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And index.html:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

        <title>polymerbasic</title>
        <meta name="description" content="polymerbasic description">


        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

        <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="/src/polymerbasic-app/polymerbasic-app.html">
      </head>
      <body>
        <polymerbasic-app></polymerbasic-app>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does the console display any kind of error? I have tested your code in Chrome (65.0.3325.162) and Safari (11.0.3) in Mac (High Sierra) and it works perfectly in both browsers.

Comment: That's weird as in Safari, same version as you, it hangs when I select and highlight the text Bullet One, Two and Three and then click on the button. Did you select and highlight the text before clicking on the button? Thank for helping.

Comment: Yes, I did, and everything worked as expected. I even tested your code in Chrome (63.0.3239.108) in Linux and it worked too.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again and it's still hanging using Safari (11.0.3) in Mac (High Sierra). I've edited and included the full code to make sure you are doing the same. I'm using Polymer 2.6.0 and webcomponentsjs 1.1.1. It only hangs when you select/highlight two or more lines of text to make into an unordered list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the full source code, the versions of Polymer and webcomponents.js and when it hangs using Safari. I will try it again later.